# При нажатии Enter прога вылетает

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller

1. есть калькулятор треугольников с помощью питона
2. импортировал в `.ехе` через `pyinstaller`
3. при введении чисел всё норм пока не нажать **Enter** для расчёта- тупо вылетает

помогите, пожалуйста

```py
import math
z =int(input('что хочешь найти? \nнапиши цифру \n1)гипотенузу прямоугольного треугольника \n2)площу треугольника \n3)катет за гипотенузой'))
def h ():
    a =int(input("катет№1"))
    b =int(input('катет№2'))
    return math.sqrt((a ** 2) + (b ** 2))
def g ():
    a1 =int(input("высота треугольника"))
    b1 =int(input("основа относительно высоты"))
    return (0.5*a1*b1)
def j ():
    n =int(input("гипотенуза? "))
    m =int(input("катет№1? "))
    return math.sqrt((n**2)-(m**2))
if (z==1):
    print(h())
elif (z==2):
    print(g())
elif (z==3):
    print(j())
else :
    print("пока-что дорaбатываю")
```

Comment: Как собирали в ехе?

Comment: Она не вылетает, а завершается с кодом 0. А это значит, что программа выполнила все заданные функции и успешно закрылась. Чтобы она не закрывалась, можно использовать в конце функции time.sleep(время в секундах). Или заключить в цикл блок с условиями где проверяется `z`

Answer (score 1):

Программа выполнилась и закрылась, нет никакой ошибки. Чтобы прога не закрывалась, добавьте `input()` в конец, в таком случае она выведет ответ и для закрытия нужно будет нажать `Enter`